# How did Daredevil know the journalist will throw a cigarette?

Tags: plot-explanation, daredevil

In Daredevil (2003), Daredevil already arranged his logo in fuel form. When the journalist visited the murder scene, he throws a cigarette on the fuel form and it forms a **DD logo**.

[image]

How did Daredevil know that the journalist will throw a cigarette?

Comment: It's also highly unlikely to [work with fuel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMrj9VFl2cY) because a cigarette won't ignite it and the fumes are long gone. And it makes little sense that not a single cop noticed the symbol or even stepped on that exact area while investigating the crime scene; it should've been just a big smudge by now. I could go on, if you want. ;) As said above, it seems a cool look trumped all logic there.

Comment: considering how most of these movies abandon all reason and logic, this is another prime example. they probably thought this would work, given this is a comic based movie, and because those always work

Comment: It's schlock.  In order to keep the liquid fuel in that tight a line on a floor, you'd have to create a channel, because liquid will run and spread.  The scene was obviously manufactured for impact.  This is sometimes referred to as "Suspension of Disbelief" in a movie.  Sometimes you just need to accept what's there and go for the ride.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now first of all, as already pointed out in the other answers and in the comments, **this scene is far from plausible**. Above the matter of knowing where people throw their cigarettes, you also have considerations of the fuel staying in place, noone else noticing the pool of fuel lying around, or Daredevil taking the time to construct it. **This scene is simply played for effect** and you have to accept that it might not be backed entirely plausibly.

However, you might notice that the journalist, in his attempt to convince the detective (or call him out on his dishonesty) that it is indeed the infamous Daredevil who is behind this, *deliberately* throws his cigarette into the fuel in order to light it. This suggests, that it is actually **Daredevil's modus operandi to leave such burning marks and the journalist is very well aware of that**. This explains why the journalist knew to throw his cigarette down (if we ignore that he also knew *exactly* where) and it might as well explain how Daredevil knew that he was going to do that: you can say **he leaves his mark specifically for the "initiated"**, who know how/where to look for it.

Comment: Didn't Eric Draven do something similar in The Crow? Don't remember if he lit it himself or if the cop did later, though.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a thought: The journalist knew Daredevil was responsible because he had gotten to the scene before the cops and saw it go down.  *The journalist* is the one who put the double-D on the floor, precisely so he could come in later and light it up.  He's *yanking the cops' chain* to try to get them to acknowledge the existence of Daredevil *for the record*.